# Replace "Add File" link with a single file upload input?

Tags: file-uploads

I've been developing a website for an artist to feature and sell their artwork. Each piece of artwork has its own channel entry, and currently, there are a number of "File" fields so the artist can upload various views (e.g., landscape, portrait) for each artwork.

They've created all of the artwork entries and are now going back through and adding all of the various view images. However, they find EE's upload process tedious for this particular work.

Basically, they want to bypass EE's built-in file browser entirely. They'd like to replace the "Add File" link with a single file upload input field à la the old nGen File fieldtype so they can upload images directly.

I've looked and looked and can't find anything to fit the bill. I thought the "Show existing files?" option for "File" fieldtypes might be the solution, but that's only on the front-end, not the CP.

The site is currently running on v2.10.1, FWIW.

Comment: Why don't take advantage of a Matrix field  with Matrix multiupload? You can handle different image layout options with an additional column with a P&T field type select or switch to pass info about layout characteristics.

Comment: My original plan was to do something like that. However, the client wants to do some stuff on the front-end that is a lot easier to do if each view option is its own unique field.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was able to develop an alternative solution using the Channel Images add-on.

Comment: To avoid question/answer collisions and help others, could you expand this answer on how you solved your issue?